# Interrupting unknown thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the following (simplified) class, designed to allow my entire component to enter some interim state before completely stopping. 
(The purpose of the interim state is to allow the component to complete its existing tasks, but reject any new ones). 
The component might be started and stopped multiple times from any number of threads.

```
class StopHandler {
    boolean isStarted = false;

    synchronized void start() {isStarted = true;}

    //synchronized as I do want the client code to block until the component is stopped.
    //I might add some async method as well, but let's concentrate on the sync version only.
    synchronized void stop(boolean isUrgent) {
        if (isStarted) {
            if (!isUrgent) {
                setGlobalState(PREPARING_TO_STOP); //assume it is implemented
                try {Thread.sleep(10_000L);} catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
            }
            isStarted = false;
    }
}
```

The problem with the current implementation is that if some client code needs to urgently stop the component while it is in the interim state, it will still have to wait. 
For example:

```
//one thread
stopHandler.stop(false); //not urgent => it is sleeping
//another thread, after 1 millisecond:
stopHandler.stop(true); //it's urgent, "please stop now", but it will wait for 10 seconds
```

How would you implement it? 
I might need to interrupt the sleeping thread, but I don't have the sleeping thread object on which to call '*interrupt()*'.

Comment: Why a synch method here ? Since you don't get a parameter for the `isStarted` variable, even if I call it 10times, I know what the result will be at the end `isStarted = false;` By the way, you probably want to change the state after the sleep (it is not `PREPARING_TO_STOP` after the sleep but `STOPPING` ;) )

Comment: Because if you call it 10 times from different threads, you want them to happen one after another. With 'isUrgent=false' it should take you 100 seconds. If you try to start it while it is in the process of stopping, it should also wait.

Comment: So it should take 100sec to get `isStarted` to `false` ? Then you have a problem since the first "none urgent" call will change the value after 10sec and the following threads would not do anything since the first condition is false. You can always synchronize the "none urgent" block and manage a waiting queue if you want to change the value only when every waiting call are done.

Comment: Sorry, I meant start(), stop(false), start(), stop(false), etc. 10 times. It should take about 100 seconds (may be less), even though the calls are nearly simultaneous.

Answer (score 1):

How about storing a reference to current Thread (returned by Thread.currentThread()) in a field of StopHandler directly before you call sleep? That would allow you you to interrupt it in the subsequent urgent call in case the Thread is still alive.

Comment: This might work, but it seems kind of 'too manual'. I thought may be someone could suggest usage of different java concurrency constructs, such as latch etc.

Comment: Good idea anyway

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a better solution than the one suggested by Lars.
Just need to encapsulate the sleep management for completeness.

```
class SleepHandler {
        private final ReentrantLock sleepingThreadLock;
        private volatile Thread sleepingThread;

        SleepHandler() {
            sleepingThreadLock = new ReentrantLock();
        }

        void sleep(long millis) throws InterruptedException {
            setSleepingThread(Thread.currentThread());
            Thread.sleep(millis);
            setSleepingThread(null);
        }

        void interruptIfSleeping() {
            doWithinSleepingThreadLock(() -> {
                if (sleepingThread != null) {
                    sleepingThread.interrupt();
                }
            });
        }

        private void setSleepingThread(@Nullable Thread sleepingThread) {
            doWithinSleepingThreadLock(() -> this.sleepingThread = sleepingThread);
        }

        private void doWithinSleepingThreadLock(Runnable runnable) {
            sleepingThreadLock.lock();
            try {
                runnable.run();
            } finally {
                sleepingThreadLock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
```

With this helper class, handling of the original problem is trivial:

```
void stop(boolean isUrgent) throws InterruptedException {
    if (isUrgent) {sleepHandler.interruptIfSleeping();} //harmless if not sleeping
    try {
        doStop(isUrgent); //all the stuff in the original 'stop(...)' method
    } catch (InteruptedException ignored) {
    } finally {
        Thread.interrupted(); //just in case, clearing the 'interrupt' flag as no need to propagate it futher
    }
```